# I'm trying to change every letter in a given string with the letter following it in the alphabet using custom input

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

#include<string>

using namespace std;

string pass(string a){

    int i=0;
    string c[100];
    char d;
    
    while(a[i]!='\0'){
     
     d = a[i];

     if(d>='a'&& d<='z'){
         d++;
         c[i]=d;
     }
     else if(d>='A' && d<='Z'){
         d++;
         c[i]=d;
     }
     else{
           c[i]=d;
     }
     i++;
    }
    
    for(int k=0; k<i; k++){
        cout<<c[k];
    }

    
    }



int main(){

string x;

getline(cin,x);

pass(x);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my solution.

I was looking for this kind of problem for a while but all I got was for pre-defined inputs. So, I passed a string from the main function.

I used a `while` loop to store every letter with the following letter (EX "a -> b") in another array "c". I then print the copied array using a loop.

Can we make it shorter?

Comment: What should happen to the character `z` and what about the digits like `1` etc?

Comment: For characters other than a-z & A-Z it will print the same (no change). Ex abc@13 -> bcd@13. And yes i made a huge mistake for the ‘Z’ because in circular order letter ‘A’ comes after ‘Z’.

Comment: You should call `std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), advanceChar);` then you just need to write `char advanceChar(char)`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a separate array called `c`. You can create an `output` string and iterate through it and increment the characters as shown below:

```
int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input); 
    
    std::string output(input);
    for(char &c: output)
    {
        ++c;
    }
    std::cout<<"input was: "<<input<<std::endl;
    
    std::cout<<"changed string is: "<<output<<std::endl;
    
}
```

Comment: But what if `c` isn't a letter? Or what if it's a `z` or a `Z`?

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes i asked the same question to the OP. But he didn't replied yet. So for now i am assuming that whatever the character it will be incremented. I don't think that there is any UB in my program that may invalidate my answer? If OP says(in future) that he don't want to increment the digits or the last character `z` then i will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a better (and shorter) implementation for your code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

char NextAlpha(char character)
{
    if (character == 'Z') return 'A';
    else if (character == 'z') return 'a';

    return character + 1; // Can be replaced by 'char((int)character + 1);'
}

int main() {

    std::string input;

    getline(std::cin, input);

    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
    {
        input[i] = NextAlpha(input[i]);
    }

    std::cout << input;
    return 0;
}
```

The NextAlpha function returns the next alphabet by adding 1 to the character, but a more understandable version of it will be firstly converting the given character into an int as such:

```
(int)character
```

..which basically means getting the ascii value of that character. Now we add 1 to the int:

```
(int)character + 1
```

..and then convert it back to char

```
char((int)character + 1)
```

..but here I've not used this way because **++character** looks a lot more cleaner.

The exceptions are defined before the return statement.

In the main function, we have a loop that iterates through all of the characters in the given string, and for each character, it does the following:

```
// Set the character at index 'i' of string 'input' to the next character in the alphabet.
input[i] = NextAlpha(input[i]);
```

Also, consider not using the following in your code:

```
using namespace std;
```

..as it's considered as bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have an error in your code: your `pass` function is declared as returning a `string` but it doesn't return anything. Actually, you don't *need* to return anything – just pass the string *by reference* and make any required changes to its content "in place".

Second, you should be aware that the C++ Standard does **not require** that the Latin letters (lower- and upper-case) be represented by contiguous, sequential values (though in the ASCII system, used in most implementations today, they are).<sup>1</sup>

Third, you don't need so many loops, and you don't need to repeat the `c[i]=d;` statement in the `if`, `else if` and `else` blocks.

I'm not sure what you want to do with the 'z' and 'Z' characters but, in the code below, I'm assuming these should "wrap around", to 'a' and 'A', respectively.

So, here's a way to do what you want more concisely, and which *doesn't* depend on the implementation's specific representation values for Latin letters:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

void pass(std::string& a) // Pass by reference (using "&") - changes will be kept.
{
    const std::string Lowers{ "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" };
    const std::string Uppers{ "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" };
    size_t p;
    for (auto& c : a) { // Note the "&" again: changes to c will be reflected in the corresponding "a" element
        if ((p = Lowers.find(c)) != std::string::npos) {
            c = Lowers[++p % 26]; // 'z' wraps round to 'a'
        }
        if ((p = Uppers.find(c)) != std::string::npos) {
            c = Lowers[++p % 26]; // 'Z' wraps round to 'A'
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string x;
    std::getline(std::cin, x);
    pass(x);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have moved the output of the transformed string to the `main` function (and simplified it somewhat); generally, a function should do only the task it is set – which, in this case is to make the transformation. The subsequent display of the transformed string should be left to the calling module.

---

<sup>1</sup> The [EBCDIC](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Emeesh/cmsc311/clin-cmsc311/Lectures/lecture6/ebcdic.html) system, for example, doesn't have the Latin letters in a contiguous sequence. You *could* use the `std::islower()`, `std::isupper()` and/or `std::isalpha()` functions to check for letters, but you would still need some sort of "data table" to determine what the 'next' character should be, unless you *assume* an ASCII or compatible encoding system.